# In Django 1.6 - how to use a pre-existing database for unit tests? (--keepdb flag)

Tags: django, testing

We are using Django 1.6.x for our codebase and there are no unit tests for the code.

I want to begin to implement unit tests on the codebase and we have a Oracle database we can use for the task. On other codebases we maintain, I can use the --keepdb flag to prevent django from creating/tearing down the database.

Apparently in earlier versions of Django this flag doesn't exist.

Created a custom settings file but I cannot figure out how to prevent the modification of db tables I do not have permissions for.

Comment: You should really upgrade. The support of Django-1.6 ended on April 1, **2015**... that's more than 1'500 days ago.

Comment: I do not have the authority for that. The employer runs a skeleton staff, so we have to do what we can.

Comment: You are looking for a technical solution for what seems to be a problem with your organization. You should be allowed to create a test database.

Comment: does this help? https://gist.github.com/Satchitananda/d47e7aa298757c24efc4